# Command + Tab on Big Sur only Cycles Apps - Don't alternate back and forth between 2 Apps

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

As the title says, I remember Command + Tab used to cycle between only 2 Apps. So, if I had 10 Apps opened it would cycle to the next in only one Command + Tab press and then BACK to the App it cycled with another press.

On Big Sur it seems to only cycle forward. If I want to cycle between two Apps I have to press Tab while holding Command through the entire line of opened Apps.

I just tested on an old El Capitan and confirmed that it cycle back and forth.

Anyone knows how to change this?

Comment: Add shift to go backwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also lift cmd before pressing cmd + tab again, you will cycle through the recent 2 apps, only:

[image: Lifting cmd between cmd + tab presses]
(you can do this much faster, just press and release both cmd and tab rapidly to see how your focus goes back and forth between the two recent apps)

Alternatively, hold cmd + shift and press tab to cycle back:

[image: back and forth with or without shift]
(if you do this without pressing cmd + tab, initially, you will move to the less recent app, though)

Comment: I think this should say, "if you lift off Cmd while Tab is still pressed down".  This is how it works for me.  Think of it as a "fast" switch, and basically just release both keys very quickly, and you will switch back to the previous app.

Comment: If you lift cmd while holding tab, you get the same effect like releasing both keys at the same time. I edited my answer to be more clear. Basically you just lift cmd and tab before pressing cmd and tab together, again. You are right on your final statement.